# Optimization for global and static variables

Tags: c, compiler-construction, storage, compiler-optimization

I read some topics over optimization and it is mentioned that global variables can not be stored in registers and hence if we need to optimize we use register variable to store the global data and modify that register variable. Is this applies to static variables too?

For auto storage, what if we store auto variables in register variables? Won't it faster the access from register instead of stack?

Comment: In C/C++, the 'register' keyword has been deprecated. Optimizing compilers do a very, very good job of optimization that trying to do better than the compiler in this type of optimization is not worth the effort. Creating a more elegant algorithm is worth the effort, but not in the realm of register optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both global variables and static variables exist in the data segment, which includes the data, BSS, and heap sections. If the static variable is initialized to 0 or not initialized to anything, it goes in the BSS section. If it is given a non-zero initialization value, then it is in the "data" section. See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment

As for auto vs. register variables: register does not guarantee that the variable will be stored in a register, it is more providing a hint from the programmer. See:

http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/CONCEPT/storage_class.html

Yes, it is (much) faster to access a register than to access the stack memory, but this optimization nowadays is left up to the compiler (the problem of register allocation) as well as the CPU architecture (which has a great many optimizations too complex to explain here).

Unless you're programming for a really simple or old architecture and/or using a really outdated compiler, you probably should not worry about this kind of optimization.

Answer (score 1):

global variables' values can be held in registers for so long as the compiler can prove there is no other access to the stored value.  With values that can't be held in a register themselves, declaring a pointer with [the `restrict` keyword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict) declares that a value isn't being accessed via any other means for that pointer's lifetime; just don't give away any copies and the compiler will take care of the rest.  For scalars declaring `thistype localval=globalval;` works at least as well if you're not changing the value or you've got good control over scope exits -- or even better.

You can only use the `restrict` declaration if the value really won't be accessed otherwise.  Optimizers these days can for instance deduce from your declaring the object won't be accessed in one function that a code path that does access it in another won't be executed, and from that deduce the content of the expression used to take that code path, and so on.  "[If you lie to the compiler, it will have its revenge](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/henry/)" is more true today than ever.